# Keras: "Found 322 images belonging to 5 classes."

Tags: keras, deep-learning, tensor

my data directory is

data/
train/
caramel
carre
makkne
ulluk

it is 4 class but running ouput of ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory is 5classes.
how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

1、use the command to find out  whether have any sub-directory

```
find data/train/ -type d -iname "*"
```

2、remove sub-directory

Answer (score 0):

**How to fix, for those that might run into this issue later...**

It is seems Google Colab automatically created additional folder (called `.ipynb_checkpoints`) in the sub-directory.

To fix this, you can check all subdirectories you have, then delete the one that was automatically added like this:

1. Check all the subdirectory

```
import os
# dir = os.listdir('path_to_the_directory') see below for your case
dir = os.listdir('data/train/')
print(dir)
```

2. Delete the folder automatically created by Google Colab

```
# sub_dir_path = ('path_to_the_directory/sub_directory_name') name of the # sub directory you want to remove.

sub_dir_path = ('data/train/.ipynb_checkpoints')
os.rmdir(sub_dir_path)
```

3. Wait for a couple of seconds or you can refresh the directory and check if it has been successfully removed

```
print(dir)
```